# JMeter: Regular expression extractor gets the name of the column after JDBC request returned data

Tags: jdbc, jmeter, qregularexpression

I faced some issue:
I use JDBC request for selecting usernames data and reuse it in the login request
The JDBC request returns correct data from the table
[image]

[image]

But the issue that my login request uses the column name as data, so it tries to login with the username `businessId` instead of the correct one. So when randomly JDBC request returns the first row which is `businessId` value the test returns 401 error.

[image]

Do you have any ideas on how can I get the correct values within JDBC request or extract values without column name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem was in the column name which was included in the `businessId` results. So my JDBC Request returned the values including the column name and the column name was stored as the `businessId` value.
For solving the issue I use ForEach Controller where **Input Variable Prefix**: `businessId` and **Output variable name**: `currentId`

Answer (score 0):

As per [JDBC Request sampler documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request)

> If the Variable Names list is provided, then for each row returned by a Select statement, the variables are set up with the value of the corresponding column (if a variable name is provided), and the count of rows is also set up. For example, if the Select statement returns 2 rows of 3 columns, and the variable list is A,,C, then the following variables will be set up:

> ```
> A_#=2 (number of rows)
> A_1=column 1, row 1
> A_2=column 1, row 2
> ```

So you don't need the Regular Expression Extractor, you need to define "Variable names" like:

[image]

and first row value can be referenced as `businessId_1`, second as `businessId_2`, etc.

More information: [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter)

Comment: I entered the variable name into the Variable Names field but it still fails and the login request uses column name instead of value. I should exclude somehow the column name from the reusable data value.

Comment: disable or better delete the regular expression extractor

Comment: Yes, I did it the first of all.

Comment: I have removed the extractors and in this case, the debug sampler shows that businessId=null. The variables field in the JBDC request is set.